# Understanding Rx.Net with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, rx.net

I'm trying to understand why the OnNext event doesn't work the way I want to make it works, and if there is a way to make it works.

By doing this, the subscription in the MainPage class never received the OnNext event. Certainly, if I write the subject in the InfoStorageService class, it works, but I would like to keep the subject in a separate class so that all other classes, that I can have, can use it and the MainPage class receives the data.

***There are the code:***

**RxNetHandler Class** to handle the subject

```
public class RxNetHandler
{
    public readonly ReplaySubject<List<InfoDto>> InfoSubject = new(1);

}
```

**InfoStorageService Class** To get data from external server

```
public class InfoStorageService
{
    private readonly RxNetHandler _rxNetHandler = new();

    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private List<InfoDto> _infos = new();


    public InfoStorageService()
    {
        InitHttps();
    }


    public async Task GetInfosDetails()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1");
        var content = response.Content;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _infos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InfoDto>>(jsonResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        _rxNetHandler.InfoSubject.OnNext(_infos);
    }
 }
```

**MainPage Class**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly RxNetHandler _rxNetHandler = new();
    private readonly InfoStorageService _infoStorage = new();
    private List<InfoDto> _infos = new();

    private IDisposable _disposed;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitData();
    }

    // Methode that is triggered when the page appearing
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        _disposed = _rxNetHandler.InfoSubject.Subscribe(
            infos =>
            {
                _infos = infos;
            },
            () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ completed ]");
            }
        );

    }

    // Methode to get data from the external server
    private async void InitData()
    {
        await _infoStorage.GetInfosDetails();
        InfoListView.ItemSelected += InfoListOnItemSelected;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you check what is called first ? You basically should subscribe before `GetInfosDetails`

Comment: also `async void` ... without `await`  ... smells baddly

Comment: @Selvin I tried as you said to Subscribe before GetInfoDetails and it doesn't work

Comment: Do some debbuging ... You will not catch exception without await ... https://dotnetfiddle.net/pp1qCI

Comment: @Selvin In your code there is no Rx.Net code. So I do not understand. :)

Comment: also ... you are using different instances of `ReplaySubject` ... but again ... you may end with `throw new Exception(...)` (so `OnNext` will never called) and you will never know about this exception

Comment: @Selvin Yes, I saw, and the problem comes from this. You're right. But with my low knowledge of programming, I don't know what can I do.

Comment: @Selvin Well the solution was to make the class RxNetHandler ``static``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make the class RxNetHandler static:

```
public static class RxNetHandler
{
    public static readonly ReplaySubject<List<InfoDto>> InfoSubject = new(1);

}
```